# New to ClickHouse, can't create local host

Tags: clickhouse

I'm new to clickhouse and trying to get started. I've installed all the packages needed to be able to use it on my computer (ubuntu 16.04) but when I use the clickhouse-client command I get the following:

```sh
ClickHouse client version 20.3.4.10 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Code: 516. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect or there is no user with such name.
```

Do anyone know what I should do?

Comment: It needs to pass user and password - *clickhouse-client --password your_password --user default* (see base options - https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/cli/#command-line-options).

Comment: When you install CH you entered a default's password. It saved in /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml . You can remove this file.

Comment: That's because the first time you installed ClickHouse you have entered the default password and you need to provide it now. Check this example https://theflashreads.com/clickhouse-code-516-dbexception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the Password here:

Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml
```

Source : https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/configuration-files/

Answer (score 0):

That's because the first time you installed ClickHouse you have entered the default password so you must provide that one as an argument to the clickhouse-client e.g

```
clickhouse-client --password=your-password
```

[reference](https://theflashreads.com/clickhouse-code-516-dbexception)